# In Container.php line 906: Target class [cache] does not exist. Laravel

Tags: composer-php, laravel-8

I try to install liberu-ecommerce but i have these error when i run php artisan serve
I did clear cache using `php artisan cache:clear`
I did also `composer dump-autoload`

```
In Container.php line 906:

  Target class [cache] does not exist.


In Container.php line 904:

  Class "cache" does not exist
```

This is the log :

```
[2024-03-14 13:05:36] laravel.ERROR: Target class [cache] does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [cache] does not exist. at C:\\laragon\\www\\ecommerce-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php:906)
[stacktrace]
#0 C:\\laragon\\www\\ecommerce-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(787): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build('cache')
#1 C:\\laragon\\www\\ecommerce-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(1024): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve('cache', Array, true)
#2 C:\\laragon\\www\\ecommerce-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php(723): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve('cache', Array)
#3 C:\\laragon\\www\\ecommerce-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(1009): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make('cache', Array)
#4 C:\\laragon\\www\\ecommerce-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\helpers.php(120): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make('cache', Array)
#5 C:\\laragon\\www\\ecommerce-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\helpers.php(241): app('cache')
#6 C:\\laragon\\www\\ecommerce-laravel\\config\\app.php(19): cache('site_settings.a...', 'Laravel')
#7 C:\\laragon\\www\\ecommerce-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration.php(91): require('C:\\\\laragon\\\\www\\\\...')
#8 C:\\laragon\\www\\ecommerce-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration.php(72): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFile(Object(Illuminate\\Config\\Repository), 'app', 'C:\\\\laragon\\\\www\\\\...', Array)
#9 C:\\laragon\\www\\ecommerce-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration.php(39): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->loadConfigurationFiles(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Object(Illuminate\\Config\\Repository))
#10 C:\\laragon\\www\\ecommerce-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application.php(307): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\LoadConfiguration->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#11 C:\\laragon\\www\\ecommerce-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(470): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#12 C:\\laragon\\www\\ecommerce-laravel\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel.php(194): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#13 C:\\laragon\\www\\ecommerce-laravel\\artisan(35): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Input\\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Output\\ConsoleOutput))
#14 {main}
```

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to Composer itself? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Same problem here : https://github.com/nWidart/laravel-modules/issues/1529